# HttpContext.User becomes empty on Redirection after Successful Okta Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, okta

I am using a .NET 6 Razor page application (Not MVC) where I need to implement SSO Authentication (Okta).

For this, I have created a MVC controller inside my Razor page application (I know it's Strange approach) and enabled routing in program.cs like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers(); // Map attribute-routed API controllers
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); // Map conventional MVC controllers using the default route
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();//map razor pages
});
```

Now I have a Page called `Privacy` which I have decorated with Authorize attribute, in this page if the user is un-autneticated, I am redirecting for Okta Authentication.

```
    [Authorize]
    public void OnGet()
    {
        string UserName = User.Identity.Name;  
      
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName)) 
            Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
    }
```

Now The Okta authentication is working fine, I get the Okta login sreen, I sign in into the page, and it gets redirected back to my controller, with all the required claims set correctly. (I can verify it in the Quick Watch in the HttpContext.User object that I am setting).

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login()
    {            
        var oktaResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        if (oktaResult.Succeeded)
        {
            HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(oktaResult.Principal.Identity);
            return RedirectToPage("/Privacy");  // <--- Here is the problem
        }

        return Challenge(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

The problem is, after the redirection back to the `/Privacy` page the `HttpContext.User` object becomes blank again.

I am not able to figure out why. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Make sure that you call the middleware in the order like below: UseRouting, UseAuthentication, UseAuthorization, and UseEndpoints.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. I used UseEndpoints before UseAuthentication that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Cookie Policy is set right.

```
 app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the middleware in the order like below: UseRouting, UseAuthentication, UseAuthorization, and UseEndpoints.

```
    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
    endpoints.MapControllers(); // Map attribute-routed API controllers
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute(); // Map conventional MVC controllers using the default route
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();//map razor pages
   });
```

You can read [Configure Identity services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-identity-services) to know more.

Comment: Hi @Bluemarble, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thank you very much.